# Auditd detects file changes in some paths but doens't work in others

Tags: auditd

I'm new to Auditd, I'm trying to watch for changes for some files but I can't get it to work, here are my example rules:

```
-D

# this works
-a always,exit -F path=/home2/ubuntu/test -F perm=war -F key=test2
# this doesn't
-a always,exit -F path=/home/ubuntu/test -F perm=war -F key=test
```

I always restart the service after editing the rules.

To tell if it works or not I keep a tab with `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log`, and I touch the test files. When I touch the first, few new lines are immediately added to the log. With the second, nothing happens.

```
root@myserver:/# ls -lah /home2/ubuntu/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 10 13:15 /home2/ubuntu/test
root@myserver:/# ls -lah /home/ubuntu/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 10 13:15 /home/ubuntu/test
```

`/home/ubuntu` is the default home of my user (I'm on aws ec2, on official ubuntu ami)

`/home2/ubuntu` I've just created to debug my problem, with `mkdir -p /home2/ubuntu`

When i (re)start the audit service, I get this suspicious line but I don't know what it means:

```
type=PATH msg=audit(1691674288.688:399557): item=0 name="/home/ubuntu/test" nametype=UNKNOWN cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
```

I've tried altering the permissions and/or ownership of the test files, and of the directories containing them, nothing changed. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: The *only* practical difference is that running auditd from /home works on a folder in /home2, but not in /home.  Perhaps something at https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/customized-file-monitoring-auditd/ can help.